How to Enable PIN Authentication for Belgian eID with GDM
I am trying to set up my PC to use my Belgian eID for authentication. I managed to get pam_pkcs11 working, and authentication via the command line works more or less. However, I'm having trouble configuring GDM to prompt for the PIN of my Belgian eID card during login.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Installed pam_pkcs11 and configured it.
Verified that the eID card is detected and can authenticate via command line (e.g. authentication for a sudo-command).

/etc/pam_pkcs11/pam_pkcs11.conf
pam_pkcs11 {
  
  nullok = true;
  debug = true; 
  use_first_pass = false;
  try_first_pass = false;
  use_authtok = false;
  card_only = false;
  wait_for_card = false;
  screen_savers = xfce4-screensaver, mate-screensaver, gnome-screensaver, kde4-kscreensaver, kscreensaver, xscreensaver;
  use_pkcs11_module = beid;

  pkcs11_module beid {
    module = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/beidpkcs11.so;
    slot_description = "none";
    support_threads = false;
    ca_dir = /etc/pam_pkcs11/cacerts/citizen_ca_chain.pem;
    cert_policy = ca,signature;
    token_type = "Smart card";
  }

  mapper cn {
    debug = true;
    module = internal;
    ignorecase = true;
    mapfile = file:///etc/pam_pkcs11/cn_map;
  }

}  

/etc/pam_pkcs11/cn_map
<Firstname> <Lastname> (Authentication) -> <username>

Despite these efforts and adapting some files in /etc/pam.d, GDM does not prompt me for my eID PIN during login. I suspect there might be additional configuration steps or specific settings required for GDM to recognize and prompt for the eID PIN. There is an error coming up: "Please re-insert the smartcard."
I also tried to setup SSSD, but without success.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to configure GDM to support PIN authentication with a Belgian eID?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
